# Codeigniter my helper function

Tags: function, codeigniter, view, helper

first of all sorry if its a stupid question but I'm a beginner, and I would like the opinion of a more experienced developer.

I'm building a real estate site with codeigniter, and I have city names what are accented characters, but I'm sending these in the database non accent because of the search, and because of the other validations.

So when I select these they are non accented chars, I created a helper what converts these back accented.

My question is, is it ok if I run this helper in my view?

I mean like, the helper is auto-loaded because I will need this in 4 view files, and I call its function like this in the view

```
echo city_accent($e->city);
```

so is it a problem if I run it like this in my view file?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a helper function in view can be done, but better way as per the convention would be to call it in controller and pass it to view form controller.
like:

```
$data['someVar'] = city_accent($e->city);
$this->load->view("your_view", $data);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can do that. As long as that helper is loaded in the Controller that calls the View.

I wouldn't put it in the View however. Layout and logic need to be separated in an MVC environment. I would use the city_accent() function in my Controller and pass the result into the View by parameter.